# How to get path of all elements in lxml with attribute

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following code:

```
tree = etree.ElementTree(new_xml)
for e in new_xml.iter():
    print tree.getpath(e), e.text
```

This will give me something like the following:

```
/Item/Purchases 

/Item/Purchases/Purchase[1] 
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[1]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165185315991112/movies
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[1]/Rating R

/Item/Purchases/Purchase[2] 
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[2]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165185315991112/movies
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[2]/Rating R
```

However, I need to get the path not of the list element but of the attribute. Here is what the xml looks like:

```
<Item>
  <Purchases>
     <Purchase Country="US">
      <URL>http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165US</URL>
      <Rating>R</Rating>
    </Purchase>
     <Purchase Country="CA">
      <URL>http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165CA</URL>
      <Rating>R</Rating>
    </Purchase>
</Item>
```

How would I get the following path instead?

```
/Item/Purchases 

/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"]
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165185315991112/movies
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"]/Rating R

/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"]
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165185315991112/movies
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"]/Rating R
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you can make `getpath()` give you that. The index is the only thing that is unambiguous in a generated XPath. You can try to amend the path manually in the loop. Find the node `/Item/Purchases/Purchase[1]` and replace the `[1]` with the predicate you want, replace to the same value in all following iterations.

Comment: Can you tell me what is `new_xml` is it xml in string form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but it does the job.

```
replacements = {}

for e in tree.iter():
    path = tree.getpath(e)

    if re.search('/Purchase\[\d+\]$', path):
        new_predicate = '[@Country="' + e.attrib['Country'] + '"]'
        new_path = re.sub('\[\d+\]$', new_predicate, path)
        replacements[path] = new_path

    for key, replacement in replacements.iteritems():
        path = path.replace(key, replacement)

    print path, e.text.strip()
```

prints this for me:

```
/Item 
/Item/Purchases 
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"] 
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165US
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="US"]/Rating R
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"] 
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"]/URL http://tvgo.xfinity.com/watch/x/6091165CA
/Item/Purchases/Purchase[@Country="CA"]/Rating R
```